# Euro (html special char) sign in selenium / phpunit?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I work on Windows 7, with phpunit & selenium & Firefox.

I have this code:

```
$value1 = $this->getText("//div[@id= bla bla");
$this->assertEquals($value1, "\u20AC 1,12");
```

where `\u20AC` should be the Euro sign. I've also tried `&euro;`,  `&#8364;`,  `&#x20ac;`, but phpunit keeps giving an error, expecting some impossible character combination.

Printing `$value1` gives me the same weird combination.

Anybody knows of a way to use, check on HTML special characters or which charset I should/could use?

Comment: What character set are you using in the source file?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: It might be that the *actual* character set of the file differs from the Content-type meta element within that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP doesn't support the `\u` escape you're trying to use, so that's why that's not working.

One approach would be to use:

```
$euro = html_entity_decode('&#8364;');
$this->assertEquals($value1, "$euro 1,12");
```

Note, the above is kind of nice for readability purposes, although it's verbose and inefficient.

Other than that, you pretty much have to work out the raw UTF byte sequence, and use one \x escape per byte.  For example, the UTF8 byte sequence for U+2022 can be represented in PHP as `"\xE2\x80\xA2"`.  I believe the [euro sign would be `"\xE2\x82\xAC"`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm)

Comment: (ooops) I get: ---Expected +++ Actual  -Ôé¼ 1,12 (next line) +&#8364 1,12

Comment: $euro = "\xE2\x82\xAC"; $this->assertEquals($value1, $euro." 1,12"); The UTF byte sequence indeed. Thanx!

Comment: Maybe you need the `;` at the end of the entity? `$euro = html_entity_decode('&#8364;');`

Comment: Good catch david.  Edited my answer as well as the original question.